# Add a keyboard shortcut to visit the Jobs page

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and on other sites like [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/), there is a [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) link below the other Questions, Users and Tags links, all of which have a "Go to" keyboard shortcut.  Can we add one for the Jobs link as well?  It should look like this:

1. <kbd>G</kbd> for "Go to".
2. <kbd>J</kbd> to visit the Jobs page.

Comment: Edit rolled back because the italics were not necessary, and also because the Jobs link formatting was skewed.  See timeline.